# loading a large (over 1000) number of images

Tags: python, image

Tell me a API, or even a working piece of code for loading a large (over 1000) number of pictures?
I'm trying the GoogleImageCrawler library, but I can't download more than 50 images

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler
import time

google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(
    storage={'root_dir': 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\ImageUploadService\\images'})
start_time = time.time()
google_crawler.crawl(keyword='snickers', max_num=1000)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: What error do you get with this code? It's easy to write code that downloads 1000 pictures, as far as I'd imagine. Are these pictures somehow massive and blowing up your memory (if so, write them to disk one at a time or in chunks), or....?

Comment: Then create your own solution using automation (`selenium`) + `bs4`

Comment: @ggorlen: google api comes with a free trial thing in which you can only download few images. but the OP wants to download  `n` number of images and there is no free api to do that. So he/she is basically asking about api which has got no downloading restrictions.

Comment: You can try this one out : https://github.com/rushilsrivastava/image_search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this does it:

```py
import requests
links = [
        "https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png",
        "https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/0*UEtwA2ask7vQYW06.png"
    ]
prefix = "{YOUR_PATH_HERE}/{YOUR_PREFIX_HERE}"
for j,i in enumerate(links):
    with open(prefix+str(j)+'.'+i.split('.')[-1],'wb') as f:
        req = requests.get(i)
        f.write(req.content)
```

However this requires you to have links to the images, which might be part of Your problem.